# Rider format when invoke parameters exactly below first parameter

Tags: c#, .net, rider, jetbrains-rider

When Im using rider and I have a method invoke with multiple parameters, when I format code I would like Rider to place them exactly below the first parameter, each parameter on a new line. Instead it places them at the beginning of each line

Currently it formats them like this
[image]

What I need is this:

[image]

How can I achieve that? I tried under Editor/Code style/ C# Line breaks and wrapping tab but I couldn't find anything that achieves what I need.

Answer (score 0):

It works for me when enabling *Call arguments by '('* under *File | Settings | Editor | Code Style | C#*:
[image]